# running every time create react app command?

Tags: reactjs

Is it mandatory to run `create-react-app` command to create app every time?

I don't want to fire `create-react-app` command which provides some react module files that help to run react application.

So can you guys help me to understand, is it mandatory to every time run this command.

```js
import React from 'react';

const App = {
  return (
        <div id="root">
            <p>Hello this is first react application</p>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `create-react-app` is used to bootstrap your react application with all configurations already in place whenever you are starting out a new project. After you have setup your project you don't need to run this command again.

Comment: thanks for reply tarzen chugh but i mean if i want to create another react application then again i have to run that command so is it compulsory to run every time.?

Comment: If you want to create a new project all together, then yes. I don't see a reason why you need to do that. If you just want to practice you could just head to [codebox react](https://codesandbox.io/s/new), it will give you a sandbox to practice and when you are done just exit from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create-react-app (cra) is used to bootstrap a new react app fast.

You can use react without using it, you can run react with only react+react-dom CDN as you already wrote in your code example.

Or you can also bootstrap it yourself if you know a little webpack, you just need the react-jsx babel preset to convert JSX syntax to React.createElement calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it once and make a local copy to just copy over every time.

You also can build an app from scratch although that will take longer.

The majority of the 5+ minutes is downloading required dependencies for the app.

**NOTE:** This is not good practice as it results in never getting newer updated dependencies in your app, and you literally just keep using the old one.

If you are just making a bunch of apps to test, then that’s fine. If you are instead making a bunch of apps for production purposes, remember that part of maintenance is updating dependencies regularly as security updates are released.